# Bad Request Error when creating a JSON String from a string and a variable

Tags: python-3.x, api

Hello I'm currently sitting on a problem, thats completely baffling me. I am trying to create a REST API for our companies robot and want the user to be able to post an already created mission to it via a GUI with this function:

```
def post_mission(host, headers):

    data = json.dumps({'mission_id': item_selected.variable})
    data = data.replace('"',"'")
   
    url= "mission_queue"
    post_mission = requests.post(host + url, json = data, headers = headers)
```

this gives me a #400 Bad Request error...
however when I replace the `data = json.dumps({'mission_id': item_selected.variable})` line with `data = {'mission_id': '68754b18-bb1f-11e8-954d-94c691173c1e'}` (aka don't take the mission_id I sourced via a textbox where the User is able to search for his desired mission but manually insert it) everything works fine and whats even more bizarre if I use `print(host + url, data, headers)` for both Code versions it spits out  the EXACT same text

I hope this is understandable and someone else has an idea where I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't have to replace double quote with single quote.

Comment: yeah I figured that out as well but before I compared both prints because something wasnt working. however the only different was the quotations which is why I tried it and left it in